Gradient descent application
I'm having problems with my gradient descent function.
The scatter plot of my diagram shows a negative correlation but the line of best fit gotten from my gradient descent function shows a positive correlation.
Here is the formula I applied for my gradient descent function.

Here is my code.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ISLP import load_data

# Load the Boston dataset
ds = load_data("Boston")
# Percentage of lower status people vs House Prices
x_train, y_train = ds['lstat'], ds['medv']

# Compute cost function
def compute_cost(x, y, w, b):
    m = len(y)
    total_cost = 0
    for i in range(m):
        prediction = w * x[i] + b
        cost = (prediction - y[i]) ** 2
        total_cost += cost
    return total_cost / (2 * m)

def compute_gradient(x, y, w, b):
    m = len(y)
    w_gradient = 0
    b_gradient = 0
    for i in range(m):
        prediction = w * x[i] + b
        w_gradient += (prediction - y[i]) * x[i]
        b_gradient += (prediction - y[i])

    w_gradient /= m
    b_gradient /= m
    return w_gradient, b_gradient

# Gradient descent function
def gradient_descent(x, y, w, b, alpha, num_iterations):
    m = len(y)
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        w_gradient, b_gradient = compute_gradient(x, y, w, b)
        w -= alpha * w_gradient
        b -= alpha * b_gradient
    return w, b

# Parameters
alpha = 0.0001
num_iterations = 2000
initial_w = 0
initial_b = 0

# Run gradient descent
w, b = gradient_descent(x_train, y_train, initial_w, initial_b, alpha, num_iterations)

# Print the found parameters
print('w found by gradient descent:', w)
print('b found by gradient descent:', b)

# Plot the data and the linear fit
plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, marker='x', c='r', label='Data Points')
plt.plot(x_train, w * x_train + b, '-', label='Linear Fit')
plt.title("Percentage of lower status people vs House Prices")
plt.ylabel("House Prices in thousands")
plt.xlabel("Percentage of lower status people")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

I looked on geeksforgeeks and this is how they went about theirs.
# Importing Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_predicted):
    
    # Calculating the loss or cost
    cost = np.sum((y_true-y_predicted)**2) / len(y_true)
    return cost

# Gradient Descent Function
# Here iterations, learning_rate, stopping_threshold
# are hyperparameters that can be tuned
def gradient_descent(x, y, iterations = 1000, learning_rate = 0.0001, 
                    stopping_threshold = 1e-6):
    
    # Initializing weight, bias, learning rate and iterations
    current_weight = 0.1
    current_bias = 0.01
    iterations = iterations
    learning_rate = learning_rate
    n = float(len(x))
    
    costs = []
    weights = []
    previous_cost = None
    
    # Estimation of optimal parameters 
    for i in range(iterations):
        
        # Making predictions
        y_predicted = (current_weight * x) + current_bias
        
        # Calculating the current cost
        current_cost = mean_squared_error(y, y_predicted)

        # If the change in cost is less than or equal to 
        # stopping_threshold we stop the gradient descent
        if previous_cost and abs(previous_cost-current_cost)<=stopping_threshold:
            break
        
        previous_cost = current_cost

        costs.append(current_cost)
        weights.append(current_weight)
        
        # Calculating the gradients
        weight_derivative = -(2/n) * sum(x * (y-y_predicted))
        bias_derivative = -(2/n) * sum(y-y_predicted)
        
        # Updating weights and bias
        current_weight = current_weight - (learning_rate * weight_derivative)
        current_bias = current_bias - (learning_rate * bias_derivative)
                
        # Printing the parameters for each 1000th iteration
        print(f"Iteration {i+1}: Cost {current_cost}, Weight \
        {current_weight}, Bias {current_bias}")
    
    
    # Visualizing the weights and cost at for all iterations
    plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
    plt.plot(weights, costs)
    plt.scatter(weights, costs, marker='o', color='red')
    plt.title("Cost vs Weights")
    plt.ylabel("Cost")
    plt.xlabel("Weight")
    plt.show()
    
    return current_weight, current_bias


def main():
    
    # Data
    X = np.array([32.50234527, 53.42680403, 61.53035803, 47.47563963, 59.81320787,
        55.14218841, 52.21179669, 39.29956669, 48.10504169, 52.55001444,
        45.41973014, 54.35163488, 44.1640495 , 58.16847072, 56.72720806,
        48.95588857, 44.68719623, 60.29732685, 45.61864377, 38.81681754])
    Y = np.array([31.70700585, 68.77759598, 62.5623823 , 71.54663223, 87.23092513,
        78.21151827, 79.64197305, 59.17148932, 75.3312423 , 71.30087989,
        55.16567715, 82.47884676, 62.00892325, 75.39287043, 81.43619216,
        60.72360244, 82.89250373, 97.37989686, 48.84715332, 56.87721319])

    # Estimating weight and bias using gradient descent
    estimated_weight, estimated_bias = gradient_descent(X, Y, iterations=2000)
    print(f"Estimated Weight: {estimated_weight}\nEstimated Bias: {estimated_bias}")

    # Making predictions using estimated parameters
    Y_pred = estimated_weight*X + estimated_bias

    # Plotting the regression line
    plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
    plt.scatter(X, Y, marker='o', color='red')
    plt.plot([min(X), max(X)], [min(Y_pred), max(Y_pred)], color='blue',markerfacecolor='red',
            markersize=10,linestyle='dashed')
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("Y")
    plt.show()

    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

Looks like their approach for the gradient descent function is completely different.
The line of best fit shouldn't show a positive correlation.

I'm confused.

You appear to have nailed the fit to go through or very near to (0,0). The linear fit when you don't do that is by eye roughly y = 40 - x, but the distribution is not well represented by any straight line!

You appear to have ended up with y=x. Have you investigated how w and b change with iteration? BTW, what does least-squares regression give for your parameters?

Your main problem is that both alpha and the number of iterations are too small to get to the regression line.
You didn't provide your data, so it's difficult to test; however, when I made up some vaguely comparable data it did what you have shown with your existing code, but converged OK when both alpha and the number of iterations were multiplied by 10.
Ideally, you need a better criterion for convergence than just a fixed number of iterations. For example, you could stop when the relative change over one iteration becomes less than tolerance.
For this problem, of course, standard regression formulae would do the job admirably.

The code you wrote seems generally correct. I think the compute_cost, compute_gradient and gradient_descent functions could be written more optimized. Also, you have kept the Alpha (learning rate) and iteration rate very low, so it may not be updating itself sufficiently. My advice to you is to try again with alpha = 0.001 and num_iterations = 10000. After you have optimized the necessary functions and updated the variables as I said, you will get an output like this..
By the way, the functions are correct, they just need a little improvement.
